# paypal checkout.js popup opens and then closes immediately

Tags: paypal-sandbox

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({
        client: { sandbox: 'sandboxemailaddress',
                  production: 'dummyemailaddress'},
        env: 'sandbox',
        payment: function() {
            var env    = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;
            return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: {total: 20.00, currency: 'USD' },
                        locale: 'en_US',
                        enableShippingAddress: true,
                        shippingAddressEditable: false,
                        shippingAddressOverride: {
                            recipientName: 'John Public',
                            line1: '123 South East St',
                            line2: '',
                            city: 'Upland',
                            state: 'CA',
                            postalCode: '91711',
                            countryCode: 'US',
                            countryCode: 'US',
                            phone: '909-626-3777'
                        }
                    }
               ],
            });
        },
        commit: true,
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
        });
     },
     '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

---

Button displays w/o error being reported.
On clicking on the button the box opens up on the screen, the wait circle appears and then the box closs.   Javascript console in Firefox reports:

```
window.paypal<["./node_modules/post-robot/src/drivers/receive/types.js"]/exports.RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPES< https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3416:40
    receiveMessage https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1838:13
    messageListener https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1856:13
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

As soon as I added it, it worked:

```
paypal.Button.render({ <p>
    client: { sandbox: 'AdZo0BCkNeg-xxxlongasssssString',
        production: 'PRODUCTIONCLIENTIDSTRING'}, <p>
    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
```

Answer (score 0):

change 'sandboxemailaddress' with Client ID.
[image]